# Add checkbox, speedup process

Tags: performance, excel, vba

I've created a VBA script for my excel doc to create various Checkboxes in specific cells in another worksheet.

This works great, but the runtime of the "script" is very slow..
I would like if there was any way to speed up this process. 
I can see the script is jumping from sheet to sheet - guess this is slowing it too?

How can i speed it up?

```
        ' Add checkboxes
           Set PasteLineCheckbox = PasteLineStart.Offset(12, 0)

               ' Aftale Checkboxes
               With .OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.Checkbox.1", link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=PasteLineCheckbox.Offset(0, 0).Left + 3, Top:=PasteLineCheckbox.Offset(0, 0).Top + 1, Width:=224.25, Height:=13.5)
                   .Object.Caption = "Timeaftale": .Placement = xlMoveAndSize: .LinkedCell = PasteLineCheckbox.Offset(0, 0).Address: .Object.Value = False: .Object.BackStyle = 0: .Object.SpecialEffect = 0: .Object.Font.Size = 10: .Object.Font.Bold = True
               End With
               With .OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.Checkbox.1", link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=PasteLineCheckbox.Offset(1, 0).Left + 3, Top:=PasteLineCheckbox.Offset(1, 0).Top + 1, Width:=224.25, Height:=13.5)
                   .Object.Caption = "Forretningsføreraftale": .Placement = xlMoveAndSize: .LinkedCell = PasteLineCheckbox.Offset(1, 0).Address: .Object.Value = False: .Object.BackStyle = 0: .Object.SpecialEffect = 0: .Object.Font.Size = 10: .Object.Font.Bold = True
               End With
               With .OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.Checkbox.1", link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=PasteLineCheckbox.Offset(2, 0).Left + 3, Top:=PasteLineCheckbox.Offset(2, 0).Top + 1, Width:=224.25, Height:=13.5)
                   .Object.Caption = "Anlægsbudget": .Placement = xlMoveAndSize: .LinkedCell = PasteLineCheckbox.Offset(2, 0).Address: .Object.Value = False: .Object.BackStyle = 0: .Object.SpecialEffect = 0: .Object.Font.Size = 10: .Object.Font.Bold = True
               End With

               ' Status Checkboxes
               With .OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.Checkbox.1", link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=PasteLineCheckbox.Offset(0, 2).Left + 3, Top:=PasteLineCheckbox.Offset(0, 2).Top + 1, Width:=224.25, Height:=13.5)
                   .Object.Caption = "Ønske": .Placement = xlMoveAndSize: .LinkedCell = PasteLineCheckbox.Offset(0, 2).Address: .Object.Value = False: .Object.BackStyle = 0: .Object.SpecialEffect = 0: .Object.Font.Size = 10: .Object.Font.Bold = True
               End With
               With .OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.Checkbox.1", link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=PasteLineCheckbox.Offset(1, 2).Left + 3, Top:=PasteLineCheckbox.Offset(1, 2).Top + 1, Width:=224.25, Height:=13.5)
                   .Object.Caption = "Pågår, Internt (Igang)": .Placement = xlMoveAndSize: .LinkedCell = PasteLineCheckbox.Offset(1, 2).Address: .Object.Value = False: .Object.BackStyle = 0: .Object.SpecialEffect = 0: .Object.Font.Size = 10: .Object.Font.Bold = True
               End With
```

Thanks in advance for any help to speed this up! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one thing that'll speed it up FOR SURE is putting: `application.screenUpdating = false` at the beginning. this code makes it so that the screen doesn't show what's going on, so you wont see it happening. adding this code will have a significant speed increase.